# NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm evaluating some ORMs for my future project. I don't like EF approach for my particular goal, because I already have business objects which I want to make persistent and I want to target at least 1 DBMS except SQL Server. I did some research on telerik's OpenAccess ORM. it looks very powerful, but also very complex to learn, and there documentation is somewhat outdated as their examples doesn't work for the latest version. Now I'm thinking to try NHibernate. It looks great, but as far as I know, it doesn't have a production ready LINQ provider, which is a huge drawback for me. But I think I can live without it.

Now about the question. I have multiple assemblies in my project, each of them containing different business objects. I want to make another DAL like assembly which will handle all CRUD operation for all of the business objects which are split in different assemblies. I know that NHibernate needs xml mappings, but in my situation, in which assembly(ies) should I embed the mapping xml files, in DAL assembly or in every assembly containing business object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate 3.0 has a new query-API which is called 'Query Over', and it is very LINQ-isch.

The mapping files should be placed in the assembly that contains the business logic.

Comment: So can I have the mapping file and entity object in different assemblies?

Comment: @Davita yes you can and I typically put the mapping files in the assembly that contain my data layer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I'll go for NHibernate

Answer (score 2):

In another order of things, I want to add something which you might find handy. nHibernate does keep xml mappings for the classes, but since I'm not a huge fan of the idea, I decided to look around for something that allowed me to define the mappings on the code, the answer was a simple project called [Fluent nHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org).

With this project, you can define your mappings a class file and everything stays as C# code, ergo removing the issue with embeding the xml files in the first place.

You can look for the documentation of Fluent nHibernate, but the basic idea would be like this:

```
public class CatMap : ClassMap<Cat>
{
  public CatMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name)
      .Length(16)
      .Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Sex);
    References(x => x.Mate);
    HasMany(x => x.Kittens);
  }
}
```

I hope I can be of assistance.

Comment: +1 for mentioning FluentNHibernate. The OP should really look into that.

Comment: Thanks David. I know Fluent API but I find it a bit harder to work than with xml mapping, so I decided to go the old xml way. Thanks anyway :-) Vote up

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David's mention of **FluentNHibernate**, I want to point out that **NH3 does have it's own LINQ provider**, which is now mature enough for most projects.

I use FluentNHibernate and LINQ in my current project and am quite happy with it. You can download the latest FluentNHibernate build for NH3 at  http://fluentnhibernate.org/dls/v1.x/fluentnhibernate-NH3.0-binary-1.2.0.694.zip

Comment: I remember an old LINQ project for nHibernate like 3 years ago by Ayende Rahien, is it the same? Sorry 'bout the ignorance, still using NH 2.1 here!